# java2pdf,how to set the height of cell

Tags: java, pdf

java project
well,i have to make pdf file.
i use com.lowagie.text.Table and com.lowagie.text.Cell
i put many Cell in one Table. each Cell's width can be assign.but the height cannot.
so the pdf file is not very beautiful.the height really sucks me.anyone can help me ?thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/PDF-RTF/CellFixedHeight.htm) you can find an exemple on how to set the heigth of a pdf cell using itext.
you can pass your com.lowagie.text.Cell as a parameter to the pdfCell constructor.